# Tchaikovsky's Chocolate (from the Nutcracker)

Tags: musical-forms

What form would you say this piece is? ABA?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too broad a question. Please consider adding additional information such as the motivation behind the question or the reason there is uncertainty about ABA.